# Tableview cell not being recycled when it contains the first responder

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with about 30 items in it. The row height is static, and based on the size of the tableview, approximately 8 cells exist at any given time. Each cell has a single `UITextField` and that is it. The confusing part is when I begin to edit let's say the textfield in the cell at row 0. What happens is everything works as I would expect, until the row is scrolled out of visibility (whilst its text field is still the first responder). I would expect a cell down the line to also have a text field with the first responder status, as it is the cell that was just being edited, but recycled for another row — that never happens.

The cell at row 0 continues to hold the first responder status. I know this because I continue typing while scrolled all the way to the bottom (cell from first row would have normally been recycled by then), and what I typed is evident in the cell at row 0 once scrolled back to the top.

To be clear this is the behavior I want, but I haven't found it documented anywhere so it makes me weary of depending on it. The text entered into the cell's text field is stored as the `name` property of a model, and weird behavior would arise if a user thought they were editing the name of the model at row 0, but because of a future change to the iOS SDK, they end up actually editing the name of the model at whatever row the cell happens to be at when they're typing.

Comment: Do you really want the user to continue editing the text field when it has been scrolled out-of-view?

Comment: @DonMag That's not the point. The point is that in the current state of things they can — because of Apple's `UITableView` implementation. I don't know why a user would, but what's my alternative? End editing for a textfield when it's scrolled out of view? — surprise user! down goes the keyboard. Maybe they were just scrolling down to check the text in another item in the list. Maybe we can just prevent editing in a way that doesn't get rid of the keyboard. Implement a `UITextFieldDelegate`?

Comment: Sure perhaps, but why do any of that when the behavior I want is clearly already implemented, and all I need is confirmation that it is officially recognized.

Comment: It's not unreasonable to dismiss the keyboard on scroll. In fact, there's a property designed just for that: [keyboardDismissMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619437-keyboarddismissmode)

Comment: @shoe - I asked, because you said *"To be clear this is the behavior I want"* ... it would surprise me to be using an app and entering information into a field that I cannot see. If that is your desired behavior, I'm not criticizing, just commenting.

Comment: @DonMag Well as the person entering the information in your scenario, that would really be on you. But you misunderstand when I say this is the behavior I want. The behavior in question is not the ability to enter information into a field not visible, it's the behavior of the `UITableView` to not recycle a cell with a field that has first responder status. Official recognition of that behavior would enable me to cross off this todo item and move on with development of the rest of the application.

Answer (score 1):

I assume Apple added the `.keyboardDismissMode` to make text field resigning easier (automatic).

From Apple's Docs [dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614891-dequeuereusablecell) :

> A table view maintains a queue or list of `UITableViewCell` objects that the data source has marked for reuse.

Which seems to indicate that, in some cases (such as this one), `UITableViewCell` objects will ***not*** be available for reuse.

We *can* at least confirm this, by inspecting the queue along with the visible cells:

```
print(tableView.value(forKey: "_reusableTableCells"))
tableView.visibleCells.forEach {
    print($0)
}
```

If we view this while scrolling up and down, we can see cells being used *and* being put into the queue.

But, if start editing a field in a cell, then scroll around without resigning it, we'll see that specific cell does ***not*** get put into the reuse queue.

Does that mean this behavior will never change? I couldn't tell you.

But, combining that information along with the fact that a `UITextField` does not `resignFirstResponder` simply by positioning it outside the frame / bounds of its superview, leads me to believe the behavior is by design.